# flash video chat bug (browser screenshot)

Tags: flash, video, livechat

I observe very strange behavior in my video chat application. It's absolutely standard app: video control on the screen, connects to Wowza media server, receives video. Everything works fine, but when other side disconnects and reconnects, the first side sees strange picture for a few seconds: it looks like screenshot of the browser window contents near the flash window but twice in size. After that it sees normal video from the other side.

I didn't find any reference for such thing in Google. Tried to change wmode from transparent to window, but it didn't help. Also I can say that it doesn't happen always, only at some computers. It's possible that somehow transmitting side is the problem, so that it transmits such strange image.

Anyone saw such problem?

Comment: I've seen something similar to this, the problem became worse in Flash Player 11.2 (which has new multi-threaded video decoding). If a Video object was reused w/another stream, sometimes you would initially see the last frame from the previous stream. Video.clear() didn't help. We eventually stopped re-using Video objects.

Comment: But I don't even reuse the Video at the receiving side, it's the same stream. What I do is close and reopen the page at transmit side.